# Connection to postgres server on Azure fails when I use "sslmode=verify-full"

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

When I select "sslmode=verify-full" when connecting to my postgres server in Azure, the connection fails with the following error:

*server certificate for "`<region>`.control.database.windows.net" (and 7 other names) does not match host name "`<servername>`.postgres.database.azure.com".*

Is "sslmode=verify-full" not allowed for Azure Database for PostgreSQL service? How do I connect to my postgres server in Azure if I have a requirement to use "sslmode=verify-full"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"sslmode=verify-full" is supported in Azure Database for PostgreSQL service, however there is a limitation in the current implementation of the service.

If you require using "sslmode=verify-full", please use the server naming convention `<servername>`.database.windows.net as your connection string host name instead of the preferred host naming convention `<servername>`.postgres.database.azure.com.

This limitation is expected to be removed in the future. Connections using other SSL modes should continue to use the preferred host naming convention `<servername>`.postgres.database.azure.com.

Please refer to [How to Configure SSL for Postgres in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security) for more details.